# Auto reload browser when files are saved?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos

I'm looking for some way to monitor when html, js and css files are saved to my local harddrive and then reload the browser. I'm working with static html-files only. Preferably something easy to setup. :)

Something like nodemon basically, but for static files.

Comment: Need more info. Explain 'when files are saved'. What is saving the files? Where do those files get saved? We need to see what the relation between the saving and the browser is.

Comment: if I understand correctly, it's when developing? Iirc, build tools like gulp (and competitors) can watch your harddrive for changes and I've used it before with static files, so if this is what you mean, you could write a gulp script to trigger another node.js script. (doesn't even have to be a build script) Or does it have to be no node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reload page to load latest edits use [Live.js](http://livejs.com)

Answer (score 0):

There's [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) which comes as standalone application, browser plugin (for several browsers) and npm module to integrate into your code.

In case you integrate it in your code (with gulp for example), the setup isn't as easy anymore, and I'd rather suggest something like [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/)